# css 2 column design with split face image

Tags: css

I'm trying to accomplish the following in CSS:
[image: animation test]

So you start with 2 halves, each of them showing half a picture of someones face (these images have their face in the exact center). By some mean of interaction the sides pan out. This is what I tried first:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 414px;
    height: 736px;
}

.container__section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.container__section:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container__section--left {
     background-color: #83b1be;
}

.container__section--left:before {
    background: url('http://i68.tinypic.com/2mwzddh.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: left 50% center;
    transform: translateX(0%);
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
}

.container__section--right {
    background-color: #80bb94;
}

.container__section--right:before {
    background: url('http://i68.tinypic.com/2s7gcav.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: right 50% center;
    transform: translateX(0%);
    right: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__section container__section--left">
        <p class="homepage__section-detail">
            lorem ipsum
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container__section container__section--right">
        <p class="container__section-detail">
            lorem ipsum
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It also seems that the images aren't loaded/blocked within the code snippet here above. If someone knows how to use images?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably layer the images in a single div (in this case using  CSS-Grid) but you could use positioning...

Then use a `clip-path` to clip one in half. This property is animatable too.

```css
.image-wrap {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrap div {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.one {
  transition: -webkit-clip-path .5s ease;
  transition: clip-path .5s ease;
  transition: clip-path .5s ease, -webkit-clip-path .5s ease;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.image-wrap:hover .one {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <div class="one"><img src="https://www.placecage.com/300/200" alt=""></div>
  <div class="two">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, seems like a wonderful idea, unfortunately the support is bad for IE